# Google Sheets script executes outdated version. How can I get the sheet to load the latest script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing a script to execute from a menu item in a Google spreadsheet using the onOpen() trigger. I am using the script editor from the menu in the spreadsheet. I have been working on this for a few days, adding features and trying them out via execution from the menu. Today, my script changes are not reflected in what happens when I execute the menu pick I added. An older version of the script seems to have become embedded in the sheet and it never updates when I save my script changes in the script editor. I've tried closing everything and re-opening the browser and then the spreadsheet, but the old code continues to execute.

How can I connect the updated code to the spreadsheet and get back to where saving the code in the editor enables the spreadsheet to access that updated code?

Comment: do you have multiple scripts associated to the project? That is when you open the script editor, do you get a page to select the script to open?

Answer (score 0):

I had made a copy of my code file, and it was that copy which was running. Obviously, it had to be something stupid, and it was.